# É correto dizer "eu farei" e/ou "eu vou fazer"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugações

Tenho visto que em Portugal usamos muito o "eu vou comer" ou "eu vou fazer", por exemplo:

> Sexta-feira eu vou fazer um bolo.

Mas já reparei que nos outros países usa-se o futuro "comerei" ou "farei", por exemplo:

> Sexta-feira eu farei um bolo.

São as duas formas corretas? Porquê?

Comment: No Brasil não se usa o futuro sintético ("farei") a não ser em situações muito formais. Ou, é claro, jocosamente.

Comment: Por curiosidade, em que outros países você reparou que se usa o futuro sintético?

Comment: @erickrf São Tomé e Príncipe

Comment: @LuísHenrique: Você generalizou demais. Usa-se sim, e não de forma jocosa, porém **predomina** o uso da forma composta, principalmente no uso coloquial.

Comment: @Luciano Exatamente. Acho que um nativo falante fazendo uma pergunta como essa um pouco exagerado, nénão? [Nota para Jorge: until you go crazy]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ambas são corretas. Na primeira forma é utilizado um verbo composto, formado pelos verbos *ir* e *comer*, no presente e no infinitivo, respetivamente; na segunda forma, é usado o verbo *fazer* no futuro. As duas frases são equivalentes, mas, para mim, a segunda parece dar a ideia de um futuro mais distante: *Farei* **eventualmente** *um bolo*.

Comment: E o verbo composto é indicação de futuro?

Comment: De um futuro próximo, sim.

Comment: O que é um verbo composto? O **vou** é presente de ir, **seguido** do infinitivo de fazer.

Answer (score 6):

Ambas estão corretas. Existem 4 maneiras distintas de se expressar o futuro do presente em português:

#### 1) ir + Infinitivo

> Vou fazer um bolo.
>
> Ele vai viajar para a Europa.
>
> Nós vamos encontrar uma solução.

#### 2) haver + de + Infinitivo

> Eu hei de me casar com ela.
>
> Ele há de estar certo.
>
> Todos nós havemos de morrer um dia.

#### 3) futuro do presente

> Farei um bolo.
>
> Ele viajará para a Europa.
>
> Nós encontraremos uma solução.

#### 4) verbo no presente + algum adjunto adverbial de tempo que indique o futuro

> Amanhã/ no fim de semana/ na semana que vem eu faço um bolo.
>
> Mês que vem/ em dezembro viajo para a Europa.
>
> Em alguns dias/ em breve/ logo encontramos uma solução.

*Observações*:

I) Ao menos no que se refere ao português falado no Brasil, as opções 1 e 4 são certamente as mais usadas.

II) Nem sempre é clara uma diferença semântica entre as opções 1, 3 e 4. Mas muitas vezes sentimos que as construções 1 e 4 são sinônimas e intercambiáveis e indicam um futuro mais próximo, certo e concreto, enquanto a opção 3 tende a sugerir algo um pouco mais distante, incerto e abstrato.

III) A construção 2 é bem mais rara e, ao  menos no Brasil, dificilmente será usada oralmente. Além disso, ela pode indicar um forte desejo ou propósito (2.1), uma razoável probabilidade (2.2) ou uma certeza inexorável (2.3). Observe-se que nem sempre é clara essa distinção, de modo que a frase 2.2 "Ele há de estar certo" tanto pode ser lida sob a chave de uma forte probabilidade, como sendo equivalente a "é bem provável que ele esteja certo" como também sob a chave da situação 2.1, como equivalente a "Tomara que ele esteja certo".

IV) As desinências de conjugação do futuro do presente (3) são etimologicamente derivadas da própria conjugação do verbo "haver" (no presente) como auxiliar de futuro (2). Assim:

eu **hei** de comprar um carro novo ---> eu comprar**ei** um carro novo

tu **hás**                          ---> tu comprar**ás**

ele **há**                          ---> ele comprar**á**

nós **havemos**                     ---> nós comprar**emos**

vós **haveis**                      ---> vós comprar**eis**

eles **hão**                        ---> eles comprar**ão**

Answer (score 2):

Ambas estão sintaticamente corretas.

Todavia em Português, como noutras línguas neo-latinas, temos uma riqueza combinatória considerável nos diversos tempos e formas verbais, ora [vede](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/fazer). Assim sendo, use-as, encurtece os registos escrito e oral, e revela erudição.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, a construção "ir + Infinitivo" como tempo futuro é correta e presente em [obras](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/ir) de referência já [há algum tempo](https://www.linguabrasil.com.br/mural-consultas-detail.php?id=11562&busca=), como outras respostas já colocam. **Mas** também é verdade que ainda existe resistência ao seu uso por parte de alguns gramáticos e falantes — e a perspectiva histórica ajuda a entender o porquê:

Já em 1822, Barbosa registrava em sua [Grammatica philosophica da lingua portugueza](https://purl.pt/128) (pg. 197) o verbo "ir" como auxiliar (negrito meu):

> Taes são os nossos tres verbos [auxiliares] de movimento *Andar*, *Vir*, e *Hir*, que junctos com os infinitos, e participios de outros verbos deste modo: *Ando* ou *Vou escrevendo*, *Venho de escrever*, ***Vou escrever***; o primeiro exprime hum movimento reiterado e frequente da acção, e corresponde aos verbos frequentativos Latinos; o segundo hum preterito proximo; e o terceiro hum **futuro proximo**, correspondentes aos aoristos e futuros proximos dos Gregos.

Contudo, "ir" foi por muito tempo, em conjunção com outros verbos, usado majoritariamente ainda em seu sentido pleno (= "lexical"), i.e., com sentido de movimento — em oposição a construções em que ele é "esvaziado semanticamente" e adquire um caráter apenas auxiliar (= "gramatical"). Como Lara coloca em sua [dissertação](https://hdl.handle.net/1884/28457):

> não podemos esquecer que, no século XIV, verbos que hoje em dia
> compõem perífrases tinham apenas sentido pleno. Ao se dizer, por exemplo, *O rei vai a lutar
> em Castela*, o verbo *ir* tinha sentido de locomoção, de deslocamento no espaço.

E, embora existam exemplos antigos do "ir" auxiliar ([Gonçalves](http://hdl.handle.net/1843/MGSS-9BHMVR), [Strogenski](https://repositorio.utfpr.edu.br/jspui/handle/1/8981), et al):

- "e vai lavar camisas" — Cantigas de amigo de D. Dinis, século XIII
- "per que se *uay hindo* [=vai indo] de mal e pior" — Orto do Esposo, séc. XIV
- "[o homem] sempre vai buscar a terra" — Sermão da Sexagésima, Pe. Antônio Vieira, séc. XVII
- "Agora é que ele vai namorar deveras" — Dom Casmurro, Machado de Assis, séc. XIX

o "ir" ao menos parcialmente lexical se mantém dominante até o século XIX, como exemplificado por uma [análise](https://hdl.handle.net/1884/28457) de peças teatrais brasileiras, que mostra que o futuro auxiliado pelo "ir" suplantaria o futuro simples apenas no século XX.
Essa tendência, contudo, se acelera no século XXI e é particularmente notável no português falado contemporâneo, com uma [análise](http://hdl.handle.net/1843/MGSS-9BHMVR) (tab. 10) de registros orais recentes revelando seu uso em 98%(!) das ocorrências de futuro.

Ou seja, o processo pelo qual "ir" adquiriu seu sentido de auxiliar de futuro foi gradual mas, crucialmente, sua adoção vem se acelerando nas últimas décadas, explicando em parte a resistência que ainda existe à forma.

Outras razões prováveis para a resistência incluem o preconceito de classe ([Lara](https://hdl.handle.net/1884/28457), pg. 28) e o ensino limitado das escolas brasileiras, como lembra o professor [Pasquale Cipro Neto](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff1110200104.htm):

> [o que muitas vezes se aprende na escola] não deixa de ser verdadeiro, mas é apenas parte da história.

Comment: Pasquale também lembra da forma "ir (futuro) + infinitivo":

    Formas como "irá fazer", "irá julgar" e semelhantes causam alguma discussão. A maioria dos gramáticos as condena ou não as inclui entre as que podem substituir a forma simples do futuro, mas há quem recolha importantes registros delas. Em seu "Dicionário de Dificuldades da Língua Portuguesa", o professor Domingos Paschoal Cegalla considera equivalentes construções como "vai faltar luz", "irá faltar luz" e "faltará luz".

Comment: O conteúdo lexical do *ir* "auxiliar", ainda se nota, pelo menos em Portugal, em coisas como "vou ler para o jardim" (a menos que penses que o jardim te ouve; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/vou-em-vou-buscar-uma-ma%c3%a7%c3%a3-%c3%a0-cozinha-%c3%a9-verbo-pleno-ou-auxiliar)).

Comment: Esses 98% são só versus futuro simples? Se for, não me surpreende nada. Porque se incluirmos o presente com sentido de futuro ("Chego de hoje a uma semana"), deve ser bem menos que 98% (vê [estoutra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/%c3%89-correto-usar-o-presente-eu-vou-para-indicar-uma-ida-futura)).

Comment: @Jacinto Que interessante esse "vou ler para o jardim", gostei, mas é algo que não se diria em pt-BR. Acho que do conteúdo lexical, ao menos subconscientemente, frequentemente permanece ao menos um resquício; às vezes só a entonação ou contexto para distinguir um "vou falar com ele"  de um "vou [lá] falar com ele". Sobre os 98%, sim, é vs. o futuro simples, e compartilho de tua impressão.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não vejo nenhum livro mostrando os pronomes pessoais conjugando o futuro com auxiliar. Ex:

Eu vou fazer
Tu vais fazer
Ele vai fazer...

Acredito ser uso natural oral, mas que deva ser evitado na escrita formal, principalmente em livros, artigos, matérias jornalísticas...

Comment: Boas-vindas, Marcelo. Você consultou de fato alguns livros, ou está apenas confiando na memória? É verdade que alguns gramáticos não recomendam, mas uma busca cursiva revela que já há décadas há livros que listam essa construção, [por exemplo](https://www.linguabrasil.com.br/mural-consultas-detail.php?id=11562&busca=): "Celso Cunha em sua Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo (1985), a locução formada pelo presente do indicativo do verbo IR + o infinitivo do verbo principal é usada para “indicar uma ação futura imediata” ou “a certeza de que ela será realizada em futuro próximo”.''.

Answer (score 0):

Vou fazer o trabalho, agora.

Farei o trabalho, depois.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE, Jose. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que sua postagem constitui em apenas duas frases soltas, sem explicação alguma e, portanto, não é um resposta. Você poderia elaborar (e embasar) o que você quis dizer?