# É correto eu dizer "eu vou ir" em português?

Tags: verbos, conjugações-perifrásticas

Aqui no norte de Portugal, mais precisamente em Braga, usa-se muito o "Eu vou ir" e todos dizem ser errado, mas é mesmo errado?

> "Eu vou ir ao médico amanhã"

Comment: Sinceramente acho errado (e inútil), e não entendo porquê construções como "Eu vou ao médico amanhã" ou "Andarei/irei ao médico" não são preferidas. Acho que mesmo as línguas naturais deveriam ser usadas na maneira mais racional possível, mas nem todo o povo é racional. (Sou português).

Comment: @nbro «Eu vou ao médico amanhã» é definitivamente preferido a «eu vou ir...». Na verdade, acho que nunca ouvi «eu vou ir...»

Comment: @Jacinto no norte usa-se mesmo muito, e as pessoas têm a mania de corrigir, mas já vi muita gente com formação em língua Portuguesa a dizer que é correto mas não se usa.

Comment: Considero erro por redundância. É tipo dizer "O garoto saiu pra fora da casa".

Comment: http://ricoportugues.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/curiosidades-4-vou-ir.html

Comment: I'll quote [artefacto](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/249/artefacto) on a question I asked here about the future tense a while ago [here](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/when-if-ever-do-you-use-the-simple-future-tense-in-spoken-portuguese):

Comment: "It's not grammatically wrong (you can say, after all, há de haver, haverá, havia havido, tenho tido, se vier a vir, and so on). It's just that vou already can mean vou ir. In Portugal, no one will say vou ir, and the fact that in Brazil some people do say that is only further proof the more advanced grammaticalization state in Brazil."   In short, "eu vou fazer..." in Portugual still carries more of the original connotation of the verb "ir" in the sense of "eu vou lá pra fazer..." than it does in brazil, where it is entirely [grammaticalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization)

Comment: @Some_Guy "In Portugal, no one will say vou ir" it's not true.

Comment: @JorgeB. I suppose that's true for some regions and not others?  I'm afraid I don't know all that much about Portuguese of Portugal

Comment: @Some_Guy Yes, I think so. On Braga you can heard that but mostly you heard "eu vou" without "ir".

Comment: @StriterAlfa - Neste caso, a língua francesa é toda errada, ***n**'est ce **pas***?

Comment: Alguma coisa contra "irei"?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira não é comum, pelo menos no norte, usar o futuro. É mais comum "Eu vou comprar um carro" em vez de "Eu comprarei um carro". Nada contra nenhuma das formas, são as duas válidas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O site [Sua Língua](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/vou-ir/) afirma não haver problema. Até porque se dois verbos iguais fossem um erro não poderíamos dizer “tenho tido”, “tinha tido”. O significado do verbo está no “ir”, e o “vou” é apenas um auxiliar para indicar o futuro.

No meu conhecimento de francês básico, *je vais aller* (= eu vou ir) é uma forma perfeitamente normal de falar. Não vejo por que proibir em português como se fosse algo ilógico.

Observações semelhantes às minhas já estavam nos comentários, mas acho importante colocar esse ponto de vista numa resposta, já que a outra resposta contém uma citação dizendo que “ninguém usa”, o que me surpreendeu bastante, porque essa locução é muito comum onde moro no Brasil.

Comment: Excelente resposta, era mesmo esta resposta que eu esperava. Já agora em que zona do Brasil é que vives se não for indiscrição?

Comment: Sul, cidade de Porto Alegre.

Comment: Legal @marcus, moras aqui pertinho. Sou de Novo Hamburgo :D. Aliás, boa resposta.

Comment: Nota: No francês (ao contrário do português) o verbo ir é reflexivo. Por isso a frase em francês está correta. No português essa construção fica naquele limbo: não é considerada errada mas soa estranho.

Comment: Como assim, reflexivo? Se é o que estou pensando, não se diz “Je me vais”, e sim “Je vais”.

Comment: Não é a "norma culta" da língua, creio eu, não é que seja proibido.

Comment: Nasci e cresci no Rio de Janeiro.  Embora esteja gramaticamente correto, não é idiomático em "carioquês".  Nunca ouvi por aqui e acho que meus conterrâneos iram que é errado ou então pedante.

Comment: ***Je vais aller*** não é reflexivo. O que é reflexivo de certa forma é: ***Je m'en vais***. Em português: eu vou-me embora. Muitos vezes em português se diz: Irei amanhã. Vou ir amanhã não é errado, é feio (demais). :)

Comment: É uma questão de redundância. Como "subir para cima", está correto do ponto de vista gramatical, mas é um pleonasmo.

Comment: Não é redundante: eu vou é presente, eu vou ir é futuro; do mesmo jeito que qualquer outro verbo: eu faço, eu vou fazer; eu caminho, eu vou caminhar; eu participo, eu vou participar. A coincidência que o mesmo verbo é verbo auxiliar e verbo principal não deve atrapalhar lógica da construção.

Answer (score 12):

A minha percepção 3 que este uso não é muito comum. O uso de duas conjugações do verbo *ir* formam uma forma verbal composta sendo o primeiro uso o auxiliar, portanto pode ocorrer segundo as regras gramaticais. 
Um possível motivo pelo qual esta forma é considerada incorreta é que, em certas regiões de Portugal, é relativamente comum dizer *vou* ***a*** *ir* (talvez por semelhança ao espanhol) que creio ser incorreto.

> Conclusão: de um modo geral, ninguém diz «vou ir», apesar de não haver nenhuma regra, gramatical ou semântica, que explicitamente impeça essa construção. *[ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vou-ir-outra-vez/25508)*.

Comment: Eu acho que essa construção também é incorreta pela fato de ser redundante (justamente por conjugar o mesmo verbo), acredito que a forma correta seria "irei"...

Comment: Eu também achava isso, mas os únicos resultados que encontrei dizem o contrário.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar aqui não usamos irei, vê [É correto dizer “eu farei” e/ou “eu vou fazer”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/269/%C3%89-correto-dizer-eu-farei-e-ou-eu-vou-fazer)

Comment: @someonewithpc se ajudar eu sei que "vou ir" é correto, mas muitos acham que não deve ser usado. Eu queria mesmo era saber que alguém sabe explicar o porquê de ser correto e se devemos/podemos usar.

Comment: É por isso que não pus como correta porque a sua primeira frase está errada.

Comment: Eu vou ir achar que o correto seria dizer que eu irei.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu sei que soa mal, mas é válido. Nós aqui em Portugal raramente usamos o futuro.

Comment: "Aqui em Portugal usa-se muito o 'Eu vou ir'!?"" Devo andar muito distraído: nunca tal ouvi. Mesmo que não esteja incorreto, soa mal como o raio. Se fores amanhã ao médico, dizes _amanhã vou ao médico_.

Comment: @Jacinto parece que vivemos mesmo em um país diferente :D Aqui usa-se muito "eu vou ir" principalmente em meios rurais.

Comment: É mesmo! Tu és donde? Eu sou estremenho: vim de Torres Vedras por aí abaixo, e acabei em Setúbal.

Comment: @Jacinto sou de Braga.

Comment: "o que não pode ocorrer": pode explicar melhor esta ideia? Não entendo qual é que poderia impedir isto. E a referência não diz ao contrário, que pode sim?

Comment: É comum utilizar o presente do indicativo "Eu vou ao médico amanhã" para o tempo futuro. O uso de ir depois do vou não enfatiza o significado, apenas diz que você não sabe que vou e ir são o mesmo verbo, ou seja, não é necessário.

Comment: @AndréLyra mas ninguém respondeu à pergunta "É correto"? Não ser necessário não implica que seja ou não correto.

Comment: Os sites [Sua Língua](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/vou-ir/) e [Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vou-ir-outra-vez/25508) dizem a mesma coisa: não há regra que proíba, mas o uso é mal visto por ser pleonástico e redundante. Para ênfase deveria ser usada outra construção "Eu hei de ir", que acredito que anda meio em desuso.

Comment: A expressão "vou ir" pode ser feia, mas não é redundante, pois o "vou" aí não funciona como o verbo "ir" no presente, mas como auxiliar que denota tempo futuro. É como se fosse o "will" do inglês (embora "will" tenha origem completamente distinta).

Comment: `não é considerado correto por ser pleonástico` - parece-me que este exemplo é contradito pela outra resposta, quando nela é lembrado o exemplo muito comum de "tenho tido". (E.g.: "Tenho tido problemas no trabalho.")

Answer (score 5):

"Eu vou ir" é bastante usado no Brasil, e ainda não vi quem dissesse que é incorreto. "Vou" no caso é auxiliar, ir é o verbo principal. Não se diz "eu vou indo"? Qual o problema? A redundância, por que "eu vou" já significaria "eu vou ir"? Mas de redundâncias a língua - qualquer língua - está cheia, não é não? E "eu vou" se usa também com outro significado, o de "eu vou habitualmente", então não está isento de ambiguidade:

> Você vai à academia?
>
> Vou.

E ficamos sem saber se o segundo interlocutor está de saída para a academia, ou se a frequenta regularmente.

Comment: Eu "torceria o nariz" se ouvisse alguém dizer "eu vou ir ao cinema".

Comment: @Centaurus - E para "tinha tido", você torceria o nariz também?

Comment: Não, xará, não torceria.  É idiomático, enquanto "eu vou ir" não é.  Pelo menos em pt-BR padrão.

Comment: Não é idiomático, @Centaurus. É uma construção perfeitamente regular. Eu tenho lido, eu tenho visto, eu tenho repetido... etc, etc, e eu tenho tido também. E da mesma forma eu vou comer, eu vou dormir, eu vou ler, e... eu vou ir.

Comment: E para deixar claro que o verbo ir, quando auxiliar, não é o mesmo verbo ir de movimento, também dizemos "eu vou voltar" e "eu vou vir". Como "voltar" e "vir" são antônimos de "ir" verbo de movimento, essas construções só não são absurdas por que o verbo ir, nelas, não é verbo de movimento, é verbo auxiliar. E como verbo auxiliar, combina-se com qualquer outro verbo, inclusive os antônimos de ir-movimento, e, é claro, com o próprio ir-movimento.

Comment: Henrique   Estamos falando de coisas diferentes, e não parece que não temos o mesmo entendimento das definições de "idiomático" e "não idiomático".    Uma frase ou uma expressão pode ser perfeitamente correta do ponto de vista gramatical e, ao mesmo tempo, não ser idiomática.  É o caso de "eu vou ir".  É correto?  Sim, é.  Mas ninguém fala assim no Brasil.  E, se ninguém fala assim habitualmente, não é idiomático.  "Desculpem-me, tenho que ir.  A pressa está comigo no momento."  É uma frase perfeitamente gramatical, mas não é idiomática.  Fala assim quem é pedante ou tenta ser engraçado.

Comment: Muita gente fala assim no Brasil.

Comment: @Centaurus - https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/expressoesIdiomaticas/

Comment: @LuísHenrique   Não me referi a "expressões idiomáticas" em nenhum momento.  Nem disse que "eu vou ir" está errado. Estamos falando de coisas diferentes.  Mas encerro aqui o assunto.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil "eu vou ir" é considerado redundante e inadequado. "Vou" já é flexão do verbo "ir" portanto não há porque usar ambos. Usar "eu vou", embora no tempo presente, coloquialmente é usado para indicar ação que está para ocorrer. É muito mais popular que "irei".

Comment: Curioso, não é isso que dizem os outros conterrâneos seus. Dá para ver que há bastantes diferencias de estado para estado...

Comment: Sim. Não conheço todas as regiões do Brasil, mas já notei que pessoas do interior de Santa Catarina (não sei se é vício linguístico daquela área, estado ou mesmo da região sul do Brasil) são os que praticam "eu vou ir".

Comment: Engraçado, que em Portugal é no norte que se usa "eu vou ir" e constantemente é corrigido. E eu em pouco tempo descobri que é correto, ou seja, é gramatical.

Comment: Imagino que seja considerado correto apenas em Portugal. No Brasil não o é. Podem usar o "tenho tido" como um pretexto para defender o "vou ir" mas não é uma comparação justa. "Tenho tido" é presente + particípio passado, enquanto que "Vou ir" é presente + infinitivo.

Comment: Wander no Brasil também é correto. Até Vinícius de Moraes usa:  "Podem preparar
Milhões de festas ao luar
Que eu não vou ir
Melhor nem pedir
Que eu não vou ir, não quero ir".

Comment: @WanderStabenow Tem que ter outros exemplos também ;)

Comment: Mas do qual região? Tem muitos regiões no Brasil aonde não vai ouvir "irei" fora dum livro né?

Comment: @Some_Guy - em nenhuma região do Brasil você vai ouvir "irei" - nem vai dizer isso sem provocar levantamentos generalizados de sobrancelhas...

Comment: @JorgeB. Na Madeira (Portugal) também é muito comum o "vou ir", já o "irei" é como se não existisse xD

Comment: @WanderStabenow - veja que o verbo "ter", como auxiliar, junta-se sempre a um particípio - eu tenho tido, mas também eu tenho lido, eu tenho comido, eu tenho perdido, etc. O verbo "ir", como auxiliar, junta-se quase sempre a um infinitivo, ou, mais raramente, a um gerúndio - mas nunca a um particípio: eu vou ler, eu ia comer, eu ia andando, eu ia voltando. Evidentemente, não há "eu tenho ter", nem "eu vou ido", mas sim, de forma perfeitamente regular, "eu tenho tido" e "eu vou ir", assim como "eu vou indo".

Answer (score -3):

`Vou ir` ninguém usa porque é um **pleonasmo sintático** visto que as duas conjugações são do verbo ir. Embora sintática e semanticamente correto, diria que é como `subir para cima` ou `descer para baixo`.

O verbo ir no presente do indicativo, neste caso *eu vou*, já denota implicitamente uma ação que será realizada no futuro imediato. Em acréscimo o futuro do indicativo é bem mais curto, ou seja, `eu irei`.

Comment: Então "eu vou voltar" é uma contradição em termos, equivalente a "subir para baixo"? Acho que não; é uma construção que nunca vi ninguém impugnar.

Comment: @LuísHenrique Eu não disse que era gramaticalmente incorrecto. Acho que é todavia uma aberração gramatical, considerando que existe a forma verbal `irei`, bem mais curta. O verbo ir como verbo auxiliar para denotar a noção de futuro, é mais um processo de "desgramaticalização", ou melhor dizendo, preguiça ou ignorância.