# When, if ever, do you use the simple future tense in spoken portuguese?

Tags: gramática, conjugações, tempo-verbal

Whenever I am reading about which tense to use, most sources seem to say that constructions like *tocarei violão* are mainly used in written text, and when speaking you would say *vou tocar violão*.

Are there any exceptions to this?  Are there any situations where the two might have slightly different meanings?

In written Portuguese, are both used or just one, and if both, what is the difference between them?

Muito obrigado amigos :)

Comment: Related: [É correto dizer “eu farei” e/ou “eu vou fazer”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/269/%C3%89-correto-dizer-eu-farei-e-ou-eu-vou-fazer)

Comment: All the answers are correct but just a comment about "going to go". Please, never say "eu vou ir" "ele vai ir lá". It sounds terrible and very very wrong. Just say "eu vou" or "eu irei". "Eu vou ir" = "I will go go" o.O. Lot's of people say like that in BR though. I hate it and really hurts to hear that.

Comment: What's wrong with it though if vou is the auxiliary and Ir the lexical verb?  How is this different than the English "I did do it","I have had ice cream before" or "I'm going to go out later"?

Comment: If it's just not in common usage, that that would make sense as language is rearely 100% logical, and often things are "wrong" in a language just because they are. But it seems like you're saying it's in common usage in Brazil, so why is it wrong to use this?

Comment: @Some_Guy It's not grammatically wrong (you can say, after all, _há de haver_, _haverá_, _havia havido_, _tenho tido_, _se vier a vir_, and so on). It's just that _vou_ already can mean _vou ir_. In Portugal, _no one_ will say _vou ir_, and the fact that in Brazil some people do say that is only further proof the more advanced grammaticalization state in Brazil.

Comment: @Some_Guy Hardly anybody says "eu vou ir" in Brazil.  We simply say "eu vou".  Você vai à praia amanhã?   Você vai ao cinema no domingo?

Comment: @Artefacto Hardly anybody says "eu vou ir" in Brazil.  We simply say "eu vou".  Você vai à praia amanhã?   Você vai ao cinema no domingo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your question is about the spoken language. So is my answer.**

**In ptBR**, the future is expressed by **"verb ir + infinitive"**.  It is very rare to hear someone use the future simple for an action that is going to happen in the future. Let's examine some examples, including a few posted by Artefacto in his answer **(ptPT)**.

- **"Eu viajarei"**...sounds formal or pedantic. By pedantic, I mean that person would normally say "vou viajar", but changes it to "viajarei" to sound different, more educated, whatever. Everybody says "vou viajar" here in Brazil.
- **"Eu falarei com ela."**  Again, it sounds unusual and/or formal.
- **"Chegará o dia"**... hardly anybody says that in Brazil.  "Vai chegar o dia em que você vai perceber que esteve errado." is the rule.
- **"Nunca o direi"** People here would say "nunca vou dizer" ou "jamais vou dizer".
- **"Será que" is a set phrase**, you can't change it. **It isn't a verb in the future**, but it can refer to a past, present, or future action and will always express uncertainty about an action or the need to hear an opinion ("será que ela vai gostar?")
  eg. Será que ela estava em casa quando tudo aconteceu? **(past)** Será que ela está em casa? **(present)** Será que ela vai nos receber? **(future)**

As I said before, the future simple has little use in the spoken language. It sounds formal and is used sometimes in such situations as, for example, when someone is giving a lecture or a speech.

Comment: If you want to know about spoken Brazilian Portuguese, this is the correct answer.

Comment: chosen because it's most relevant to be as a ptBR learner (I didn't really understand how different the two languages are when I posted this question.  Your tip about "será que" was really helpful too, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

### Is the simple future used in spoken Portuguese?

Yes, it certainly is. But this needs to be qualified.

The future simple has many values. Here are some, and how they could (or not) be replaced with *ir (present) + infinitive*, *haver (present) de + infinitive* or the present. (There is also the form *ir (future simple) + infinitive*, which is similar in meaning to the simple future.)

- Quando chegar a altura, tratarei do teu funeral. (distant future without modality; fully replaceable with the present *trato*; replacement with *hei de tratar* adds an odd enthusiasm to the sentence; replacement with *vou tratar* suggests a firmer intention)
- Amanhã viajarei para o Porto. (simple futurity; replaceable with *vou viajar* and, in this case, with the present *viajo* because the adverb "amanhã" eliminates any ambiguity)
- Chegará o dia em que isso deixa de funcionar. (tone of prophecy; most commonly replaced with *há de chegar*; also replaceable, to a lesser extent, with *vai chegar*, which maybe suggests the day would be very close)
- Nunca o direi. (promise/commitment; replaceable with *hei de dizer* and, less emphatically, with *vou dizer*)
- Pagarás pelo que fizeste. (threat; replaceable with *vais pagar* and, to the extent that it is in an undeterminate future, *hás de pagar*)
- Farás o que eu te digo. (deontic modality; replaceable with *vais fazer* with the right intonation)
- Não matarás. (one of the Ten Commandments; similar to above but non replaceable with *vais matar*)
- Por esta altura estará já em casa. (probability, episthemic modality; replaceable with *há de estar*)
- Não havia sinais de entrada forçada, pelo que o ladrão terá entrado pela porta das traseiras, que não estava trancada. (logical conclusion of which one is not 100% certain; replaceable with *há de ter entrado*, which would give it less certainty; with *entrou* would sound like a certain conclusion)
- O detido será o autor de um homícidio. (alleged fact; replaceable *é provavelmente/alegadamente/presumivelmente*)
- Compreenderás que não o fiz de propósito. ("*I hope you understand...*" but a little more suggestive or forceful; replaceable with *Hás de compreender*)
- Onde é que estaremos? (rethorical question, suggests a problem; not replaceable)
- **Será que** ele já chegou? (wondering; it is a slightly more common version of "Ele terá já chegado?"; not replaceable)

Of these, the sentences expressing doubt or possibility are the most likely to be used in spoken Portuguese.

The usage is also different between Brasil and Portugal. Generally speaking, the *ir + infinitive* is more grammaticalized there (there's no idea of immediate future or going somewhere) and the periphrasis *haver de* barely exists. Translating [from here](http://gredos.usal.es/jspui/bitstream/10366/110664/1/DFM_Fidalgo_Enriquez_FJ_LaExpresion.pdf):

> The form *ir + infinitivo* in Brazilian Portuguese is more grammaticalized and in a more advanced evolutive state than in Spanish and in European Portuguese. This fact can be observed not only in that it has turned into the form of choice to express futurity (distant or immediate), uprooting the synthetic form *-rei* in the oral language, but also because it's being threatened by other forms of expressing futurity like the periphrasis *estar + gerúndio*, which is unheard of in Portugal, to express immediate futurity and to express intentional modal content, given that these values are weakened in *ir + infinitivo* in the Brasilian Portuguese norm.

Then there are sociolinguistic factors. More educated people tend to use the simple future more. On TV, the typical football coach probably won't use the future simple (except in "será que" and other limited circumstances), but more educated people will.

The general tendency is for *ir + infinitive* when it can be used.

### Are there any situations where the two might have slightly different meanings?

For someone who's not an advanced learner of Portuguese, I wouldn't worry too much about the differences between the two except for the situations where the future simple denotes probability/doubt, which the periphrasis with *ir* cannot.

Nevertheless, as hinted before, there are also other differences, but only in European Portuguese.

The periphrasis tends to express:

- A [prospective aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospective_aspect), including (but not limited to) ingressive (beginning of a new action) and inchoactive (beginning of a new state) aspects.
- A near future rather than a distant one.
- An intention rather than a quasi-expectaction.

A prospective aspect means the event time happens later than the [reference time](http://derczynski.com/sheffield/tsie/Reichenbach%20-%20tenses%20of%20verbs.pdf). Take @Jacinto's sentence:

> Em Janeiro, já serei pai.

By January, he will already be a father; the future event started before the reference time (January). "Ir" is indeed possible, but less natural. You could also say:

> Em Janeiro, já hei de ser pai.

Which is similar, but introduces more distance or detachement in the statement.

Compare also these two sentences:

> (1) Amar-te-ei sempre.
>   (2) Vou amar-te sempre.

Here (2) is merely prospective (maybe you didn't love them before), and can mean that you will start loving them now. (1) is more compatible with a meaning where you've always loved them and will continue doing so.

Let's also compare these sentences:

> (1) Eu farei o trabalho.
>   (2) Eu vou fazer o trabalho.

We can interpret the contrast in several ways:

- (1) is a mere statement of fact, where (2) signals intention of doing the work,
- (1) indicates you will do the work at some point, where in (2) you will be doing the work in a near future,
- (2) indicates that you will begin doing the work.

Note also that, with the right context, their differences are mostly flattened:

> Amanhã farei o trabalho.
>   Amanhã faço o trabalho.
>   Amanhã vou fazer o trabalho.

(*Amanhã hei de fazer o trabalho* doesn't mean the same, it is more of a commitment or reminder to yourself.)

By the way, you've asked very broad questions, if you want to know more, you can look at [the thesis I mentioned above](http://gredos.usal.es/jspui/bitstream/10366/110664/1/DFM_Fidalgo_Enriquez_FJ_LaExpresion.pdf).

Comment: This is definitely going to take some digesting, thanks so much for the thorough answer

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a matter of usage and what sounds more natural. And I'm writing from Portugal, so there's always the chance that someting sounds natural to me and not so natural to Brazilian ears. So here it goes. In spoken language you use the *futuro* mainly to express uncertainty or doubt.

> (a) Parto para Londres amanhã, *voltarei* talvez no sábado.

If you you’re sure you’re coming back Saturday you’d say*vou voltar no sábado* or *volto no sábado*. And you could say *volto talvez no sábado* too: the *future* sounds natural in (a), but it’s not compulsory. Similarly:

> (b) Que *dirá* ele quando souber?
>
> (c) Não sei se amanhã, depois de um longo dia de trabalho, *estarei* com disposição para o aturar.

You can use the *futuro* to express uncertainty even about the present:

> (d) Ele já *terá* chegado? *Estará* em casa agora?

The questions above will sound rhetorical (you're not expecting an answer at all, are only wondering aloud) or implying that you are not confident the person you’re asking knows the answer. Otherwise you’d ask *ele já chegou? Está em casa agora?*

You use the *futuro* too in structures like *by the time X I'll something* when this *something* has started before *time X*. Especially with the verb *ser*. Compare:

> (e) *Vou ser* pai em janeiro.
> (f) Em janeiro já *serei* pai.

In (e) you mean your child will be born in January. In (f) you mean that by January you’ll be a daddy already; your child may have been born earlier. It would be a natural structure in phrases like *by the time you’re back, I’ll*…
I reckon you could rephrase (f) as *em janeiro já vou ser pai*, but it doesn't sound as natural to me. Structure (f) works with other verbs too:

> (g) Quando voltares de Londres, já *terei* carta de condução; já *poderei* levar-te a passear.
>
> (h) Daqui por um ano já *estarei* na casa nova.

But in (g) and (h) you could use *ir* plus infinitive instead.

I tried to sample my memory for usage of futures tenses in literature, but the problem is that stories, except for the rendering of direct speech, don’t use the future tense much. It’s more along the lines of *once upon a time and what a good time it was there was a moocow coming down along the road*… I suppose it will be more common in contracts and formal plans:

> (i) As mercadorias *serão* entregues na sexta-feira e o fiscal *inspecioná-las-á* de imediato.

If you substitute *vão ser* for *serão* there is no change in meaning. It’s just that *serão* is more formal. *Vai inspecioná-las* is again more informal, and sounds more like a matter of facr, whereas *inspecioná-las-á* (= inspecionará as mercadorias) can sound like a prescription. (It may be the uncertainty conveyed by the *futuro* in informal language creeping in.)

One hears here and there sometimes that *ir + infinitive* applies to the near future, and the simple future to a more distant future. But I think the important difference is fact versus possibility. Compare:

> Os resultados das eleições só serão conhecidos daqui a três horas.
>
> A atividade económica em Portugal só regressará ao nível anterior à crise daqui a dois anos.
>
> O sol vai extinguir-se daqui a cinco bilhões de anos.

The difference here is that we're a lot more confident about the Sun.

Comment: Interesting. It does seem that adverbs such as "já", "então", cue the simple future.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm getting too self-conscious to analyse these things properly. But maybe what's going on is that _vou ter, vou poder_, etc. hint at a beginning. And when you refer to something at a moment X in the future (say, having a driver's license) but that something has begun before X (as in my examples (f) to (h), then may _vou ter_ doesn't sound so compelling anymore, and opens the way for _terei_. But it's not the _já_ per se: _Gosto destas novas regras; assim já vou poder ganhar_. I wouldn't say _poderei_ here.

Comment: Hás de ler aqui [esta tese de doutoramento](http://gredos.usal.es/jspui/bitstream/10366/110664/1/DFM_Fidalgo_Enriquez_FJ_LaExpresion.pdf) Podes começar na página 703 onde está uma discussão sobre "já" que me passa ao lado, mas depois discute contraste futuro simples/perifrstico. Após ler mais castelhano do que gostaria, parece-me que os contrastes são futuro remoto/futuro imediato, -certeza/+certeza, quase-previsão/intenção e aquilo a que ele chama "conteúdo aspetual prospetivo": na perífrase o ponto de origem coincide com o momento da enunciação, mas pode deslocar-se no futuro simples.

Comment: Já agora, aqui parece concordar com o tua opinião sobre um começo: "En la última (16) ["O sol vai nascer"], ir+infinitivo tiene el valor aspectual ingresivo y temporal de inmediato, recordemos que esta perífrasis sí posee valor aspectual prospectivo puede ser, entre otros, ingresivo o incoativo"

Comment: Ainda bem. Isto foi uma coisa em que eu me pus a pensar com a tua observação acerca do _já_. Depois lerei isso. Mas página 703?! Isso não é uma tese; é uma tesão!

Comment: Probably worth noting that some grammarians have considered the simple future in Iberian languages to be part of a separate mood entirely.  The A.Ll.A. actually codifies the future as the *present* of the *potential* mood.  I dunno if that term has been tossed about in Lusophone circles.  the *ir inf.* construction really only implies that an action will happen after the given time frame (and can be used in more than just the present), but lacks all the other possibilities.

Comment: @guifa Are you saying then, that _ir inf._ would be out of place in my examples (f) - ((h)? Cause I'd feel uncofortable about it there. As to the future tense being a separate mood entirely, I'd say it's a bit too much. We can use it to talk about the future. It's just that we tend not to except in formal language.

Comment: @Jacinto not at all. Those are all actions that will take place after right now. But the non-future speculative uses are not really swappable with *ir+inf*. *Ele está doente. Terá a gripe?* (*vai ter gripe* doesn't really fit) *ir+inf* can be used elsewhere though: *ia comer* (occurs after a past action), *vou comer* (occurs after present).

Comment: Oh that. I knew that already. But _quando voltares de Londres, já vou ter carta de condução_ doesn't feel quite as compelling as _quando voltares de Londres, vamos festejar a minha carta de condução_. And _já terei carta_ sounds ok in the former, but _festejaremos_ sounds formal in the latter. I wonder why that is.

Comment: @guifa and Jacinto I've revised my answer and added something about prospectivity, maybe you can tell me whether you agree.