# futuro do presente vs. futuro imediato (quando cada um será usado)

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, verbos

Eu sei que o futuro do presente é um tempo que é usado para falar de coisas que ocorrem posteriormente ao momento de falar e também em situacão de incerteza. 
Então, se não me engano, esse tempo é eauivalente **will** em inglês.

Mas, agora, que tal futuro imediato?

Posso falar que é um tempo no futuro com certeza? Então pode ser como **tobe + verb + ing** em inglês?

Comment: Majid, creio que não são duplicatas, mas já há umas perguntas relacionadas que te poderão ajudar: [when do you use the simple future tense](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/when-if-ever-do-you-use-the-simple-future-tense-in-spoken-portuguese/1272#1272);mais ["eu vou" para indicar uma ida futura](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/%C3%89-correto-usar-o-presente-eu-vou-para-indicar-uma-ida-futura?noredirect=1&lq=1). Por "futuro imediato" queres dizer coisas como "vou dormir, vou passar o Natal com os meus avós" e coisas assim?

Comment: Seria interessante dar algumas frases. Essas comparações no ar me dão dor de barriga. Também há confusão com esse will, que nem sempre indica futuro em si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Os tempos verbais que utilizamos para nos referir ao futuro, na língua portuguesa, são esses:

- Futuro do presente do indicativo: Eu ouvirei música.
- Futuro do pretérito do indicativo: Eu ouviria música
- Futuro do presente composto do indicativo: Eu terei ouvido música.
- Futuro do pretérito composto do indicativo: Eu teria ouvido música.
- Futuro do subjuntivo: Quando eu ouvir música, ficarei mais calma.
- Futuro composto do subjuntivo: Quando eu tiver ouvido música, falarei contigo.

Sobre a questão que propôs: O futuro é sempre uma possibilidade e não uma certeza! O que podemos indicar, no máximo, é a existência de uma maior confiança na ocorrência de um fenômeno.

É como nos modelos lineares de causa-efeito, em que a existência de uma variável prediz a manifestação de outra, com maior segurança. Isso é o que testemunhamos no comportamento dos objetos estudados pela Mecânica, ramo da Física. As regularidades dos fenômenos naturais nos dão esse conforto na previsão.

A linguagem se refere as experiências humanas que testemunhamos no momento em que compartilhamos essas com os nossos pares ou construímos a nossa narrativa. Portanto esse termo: "futuro imediato" soa estranho. Parece implicar algo que já aconteceu ou acontece nesse momento, garantindo uma certeza testemunhal ao fato.

Talvez o tempo a que esteja se referindo seja o **gerúndio**. Quer dizer: uma coisa que ocorre no presente e tem continuidade no tempo futuro... como, por exemplo: estou dirigindo o carro.

Não sei se é essa a resposta que procura.