# "Terei eu...." Como explicar o uso do futuro do presente para nos referirmos a um evento passado?

Tags: tempo-verbal

Intriga-me o uso do futuro do presente em frases do tipo:

- Terei eu ofendido alguém com minhas palavras?
- Terei eu esquecido de trancar a porta?
- Teremos nós cometido alguma infração quando excedemos os cem quilômetros por hora?

Como explicar esse uso?

Comment: @Schilive  Mudei as duas palavras finais da pergunta.  Não sei como torná-la mais clara.

Comment: [Relacionado, mas no inglês](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459845/2085): *“It is the **speaker's assessment** of what **probably** happened.”*

Comment: Este assunto é abordado nesta pergunta [When ... do you use the simple future..](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/when-if-ever-do-you-use-the-simple-future-tense-in-spoken-portuguese): o futuro serve para exprimir incerteza (*ele já **estará** em casa agora?*); + particípio passado, pode exprimir incerteza sobre o passado (*sim, já **terá chegado** há coisa de duas horas*).