# É correto usar o presente "eu vou" para indicar uma ida futura?

Tags: verbos, tempo-verbal

Quando queremos dizer que uma ação, como fazer o jantar ou visitar a Maria, acontece no futuro, usamos o verbo *ir* com o verbo da ação do infinitivo. Exemplos:

> (a) **Vou fazer** o jantar
>
> (b) **Vou visitar** a Maria

Já temos sobre este assunto [esta pergunta sobre *eu farei* e *eu vou fazer*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/269/%C3%89-correto-dizer-eu-farei-e-ou-eu-vou-fazer). Se o verbo da ação já for o *ir*, por exemplo, *ir aos Jogos Olímpicos*, por analogia ficaria:

> (c) Eu **vou ir** aos Jogos Olímpicos em 2020

Já há [esta pergunta sobre se *eu vou ir* é correto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/270/%C3%89-correto-eu-dizer-eu-vou-ir-em-portugu%C3%AAs). Mas pelo menos em Setúbal e com o pessoal que conheço, ninguém diz isto. Dizemos simplesmente:

> (d) Eu **vou** aos Jogos Olímpicos em 2020

O verbo *ir* parece ser mesmo a única excepção quando queremos dar a ideia que o acontecimento será no futuro: aqui em Setúbal, conjugamos apenas o verbo *ir* no presente, sem mais nenhum verbo no infinitivo, ao contrário dos exemplos (a) a (c).

As outras perguntas não esclarecem se frases como a (d) estão corretas. Será que simplesmente dizer ***eu vou*** (para indicar que irei, no futuro) está incorreto? Ou existe uma simplificação aprovada para o verbo ***ir***?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48709/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-costa-e-correto-usar-eu-vou-para-indicar-o-fut).

Comment: Eu como nativa em PT-BR, acredito que dizer "Eu vou" é comum e informal, não sei dizer se é gramaticalmente correto; e dizer "Eu irei" não é comum e é formal, creio que é gramaticalmente correto. (sou do interior de SP).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O simples presente do indicativo *vou, vais*, etc. para exprimir uma ida futura é absolutamente correto e é até muito mais comum que *vou ir, vais ir*, etc. O verbo ir é de facto excecional, mas não por ser o único, que não é, em que se usa o presente para referir o futuro; nós fazemos isso com qualquer verbo. Esta prática está aliás reconhecida na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 560-2):

> O presente do indicativo emprega-se:
>   […]
>   5.º) para marcar um facto futuro, mas próximo; caso em que, para impedir qualquer ambiguidade, se faz acompanhar geralmente de um adjunto adverbial:
>
> > **Vou** para Coimbra.
> >     (José Saramago, [*Memorial do convento*, 1982], 124.)
> >
> > Amanhã mesmo **vou** para Belo Horizonte e lá **pego** o avião do Rio.
> >     (António Callado, [*A madona do cedro*, 1981], 19.)
> >
> > Outro dia eu **volto**, talvez depois de amanhã, ou na primavera.
> >     (Agustina Bessa-Luís, [*As relações humanas: Os quatro rios*], 227.)

Agora, com quase todos verbos, creio, para exprimir o futuro nós algumas vezes simplesmente conjugamos o verbo no presente do indicativo, como nos exemplos acima; outras vezes, usamos o chamado ‘futuro próximo’: *vou ver, vou comprar*, etc. O verbo *ir* é excecional porque com ele o ‘futuro próximo’ é pouco usado, como ilustram as tabelas abaixo.

Por exemplo, o Google encontra-me aproximadamente tantos *amanhã vejo* (323 resultados) como *amanhã vou ver* (276 resultados). Creio que todos os falantes usam as duas formas, escolhendo inconscientemente uma ou outra conforme o que querem transmitir. Já *amanhã vou ir* é dez vezes menos frequente que *amanhã vou* (112 contra 1128 resultados; a inclusão do *a, ao*, etc. exclui *vou comer, vou ver*, etc., que falseariam a comparação). O que se passa aqui, creio, é que muitos falantes simplesmente não usam *vou ir, vais ir*, etc. Setúbal não é certamente caso único.

**Resultados do Google Search**

---

```
                                             Ver   Comprar   Fazer  Visitar
Amanhã + 1ª pess. sing. pres. indicativo     323     302      291     124
Amanhã vou + infinitivo                      276     255      279     178
```

---

```
                   a     ao    à    para    pra     Total
Amanhã vou        236   264   231    284    167      1182
Amanha vou ir      16    30    11     25     23       112
```

---

Na verdade *vou* para indicar uma ida futura é ainda mais comum do que os números acima sugerem. Vejamos este exemplo:

> Amanhã vou jantar a Azeitão.

À primeira vista pode parecer que *vou* é verbo auxiliar, um mero marcador do futuro do verbo principal *jantar*. Mas não é; nem *jantar* é o verbo principal:  nós não podemos dizer *janto a Azeitão* ou *jantarei a Azeitão*. (Vejam [a pergunta *vou buscar uma maçã à cozinha*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/vou-em-vou-buscar-uma-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3-%C3%A0-cozinha-%C3%A9-verbo-pleno-ou-auxiliar).) O complemento direcional *a Azeitão* significa que *vou* é verbo pleno e é o verbo principal da frase; *jantar* é, na linguagem da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, p. 1264-65), um adjunto adverbial de finalidade. A frase é equivalente a:

> Amanhã vou a Azeitão jantar.

O mesmo se passa em frases como:

> Logo à tarde vou dar uns mergulhos ao Portinho.
>   Este fim de semana vamos passear ao Cabo Espichel.
>   Logo à noite vou ver a superlua a Palmela.
>   Para o ano vou passar férias ao Brasil.

Ou seja, anda por aí disfarçado de verbo auxiliar muito presente do indicativo do verbo *ir* como verbo principal no seu sentido pleno de ‘ida’  e nomeadamente de ‘ida futura’.

Comment: Muito interessante a tua pesquisa.

Comment: @JorgeB. O que me surpreendeu foi haver tantos foi haver tantos *amanhã vejo, faço, etc.* por comparação com *amanhã vou ver, fazer, etc.* Provavelmente usamos sem nos darmos conta. *Amanhã **vejo-te** isso, que hoje não tive tempo*, n'é?

Answer (score 5):

**O uso do presente do indicativo para uma ação que vai se concretizar no futuro é, não apenas gramaticalmente correto, mas também extremamente comum.**

O futuro do presente, apesar do seu nome, caiu em desuso em favor do presente do indicativo.  Dificilmente ouvimos alguém dizer: “se você fizer a dieta, é certo que emagrecerá”. Mesmo na norma culta do Português moderno, o mais comum é ouvirmos “se você fizer a dieta, é certo que vai emagrecer.”  Neste caso o verbo ir funciona como um verbo auxiliar.

**Quanto ao uso do presente do indicativo para indicar um evento futuro, sem o auxílio de outro verbo, o ponto principal da pergunta, isso também é muito comum na língua portuguesa e não é exclusividade do verbo ir conforme usado em “Eu vou aos Jogos Olímpicos em 2020.”**

**Na verdade, o presente do indicativo é, atualmente, um tempo verbal polivalente: joga na defesa, no meio de campo e no ataque.  Ou melhor, pode indicar passado, presente ou futuro.**
Vejam os seguintes exemplos do presente do indicativo sendo usado para indicar uma ação futura:

- A que horas **sai** o nosso voo amanhã?
- Não vou poder ir, **estou** de folga no dia 23 mas no dia 24 eu **trabalho** o dia inteiro.
- Certo, nos **encontramos** amanhã às 15 h. no Cais da Ribeira.
- Estou ocupado. **Falo** com você depois do almoço.
- Amanhã a gente se **reúne** novamente e discute esse problema.
- Podes ficar tranquilo, **mando** tudo por e-mail na segunda-feira.
- Se eu acertar a mega-sena do Natal, eu **pago** todas as tuas contas.
- Você só **sai** daqui depois que me contar tudo.
- Ficou acertado que o Reino Unido **deixa** a União Européia em março de 2017.

Conforme citei acima, o presente do indicativo também pode ser usado quando nos referimos a eventos passados, principalmente em narrativas e pela mídia. Esta última abusa do seu uso e não mais somos informados de que um avião caiu ou que alguém morreu.  Ouvimos, ao invés, a informação dada no presente do indicativo, indicando um evento passado. Vajamos alguns exemplos:

- Em 1640 Portugal finalmente **liberta-se** do domínio espanhol.
- Em 1808 Napoleão **decide** invadir a Russia e **desloca** metade de suas forças...
- Com tantas preocupações, ela simplesmente **esquece** o encontro e ele **fica** esperando.
- Mal eu **entro** no escritório e já **recebo** a notícia do falecimento. Isso chama-se “falta de tato”.
- Avião **cai** na Ucrânia e **deixa** 150 mortos.
- **Morre** o ator James Gandolfini aos 51 anos.
- A terra **treme** na região central da Itália.
- Trump **é** eleito o novo presidente dos Estados Unidos.

Comment: É engraçado que eu sempre tive a ideia que se usava mais no Brasil o futuro.

Answer (score 2):

No português brasileiro é considerado correto usar "eu vou" para indicar uma ação a ser tomada no futuro, por exemplo "eu vou viajar amanhã" ou "eu vou tomar um café".

Porém "eu vou ir" é considerado **incorreto**, já que é uma redundância: "vou" é flexão do verbo "ir". Ao invés de, por exemplo, dizer "eu vou ir a igreja" basta dizer "eu vou a igreja".

Obviamente o uso de "eu vou" (presente) para indicar ação futura é uma construção popular, mas aceita. A flexão do verbo ir em tempo futuro (irei) não é de uso coloquial.

Comment: Tem uma fonte para confirmar a sua respsota?

Comment: E no caso de "tenho tido", também é incorreto por ser redundante? (Pelo menos em Portugal, "tenho tido" é um uso comum e aceite: "tenho tido problemas no trabalho".)

Comment: Concordo com a resposta acima.  Nasci e cresci no Rio de Janeiro. Embora possa ser gramaticamente correto, não é idiomático em "carioquês". Nunca ouvi por aqui e, se eu assim falar, acho que meus conterrâneos vão achar que é errado ou então pedante.

Comment: "tenho tido" = presente + particípio passado
"vou ir" = presente + infitivo

Comment: Há diferença:

"tenho tido" = presente + particípio passado

"vou ir" = presente + infinitivo

Comment: Eu tenho notado que o uso dessa expressão é típico no sul do país (pelo menos no interior de Santa Catarina). Sou do Espírito Santo e não se usa "vou ir" por lá.

Comment: Não é nada incorreto Wander, é gramaticalmente correto o uso de "eu vou ir".

Comment: Não é que seja gramaticalmente errado, é que ninguém fala: eu vou ir. Eu também não*** custumo***ouvir VOU IR....

Comment: @ANeves Uma diferença entre *ter tido* e *ir ir* é que o primeiro *ter* está completamente gramaticalizado, isto é, não conserva nada do significado próprio do verbo pleno *ter*. O mesmo não se passa em *ir visitar, ir comprar*, etc., onde frequentemente o *ir* não é um verdadeiro auxiliar, antes mantém o seu sentido próprio de deslocação. Quando se acrescenta o segundo *ir*, na minha cabeça, introduz-se uma redundância: os dois verbos dão a mesma ideia de deslocação.

Comment: @Jacinto nem sempre dá ideia de deslocação. "Vou fazer um bolo", "vou cantar", etc não dá sentido de deslocação...

Comment: @JorgeB. Nem sempre. Por isso eu escrevi «frequentemente». Mas se eu estiver sentado ao teu lado e me levantar dizendo, «vou fazer um bolo», tens a ideia de deslocação. Tanto, que se alguém te perguntar, «o Jacinto?» tu podes simplesmente responder, «**foi** fazer um bolo». Este ***foi*** dá clara ideia de deslocação (*foi para algum lado fazer um bolo*) e corresponde exatamente ao ***vou*** do *vou fazer um bolo*.

Comment: @Jacinto sim, mas porque é um futuro imediato, se eu disser "amanhã vou fazer um bolo" já deixa de ter esse sentido da deslocação.

Answer (score -1):

Muito boa a pesquisa! Eu não consigo concordar que essa forma verbal esteja correta, principalmente se estiver na forma escrita, que costuma ser mais culta.

Sinto que o idioma inglês trouxe um novo significado para o "vou", como se este fosse uma tradução para "will", mas não é. O uso incorreto do "vou" para expressar tempo futuro cria uma falha quando há a necessidade de expressar o pretérito presente.

No Brasil ninguém mais usa "vou" para tempo presente, sendo a substituição obrigatoriamente com uso do gerúndio. Hoje dizemos: "estou indo ao mercado"; quando seria muito mais simples dizer: "vou ao mercado".

A conjugação de passado também tem sido utilizada expressar futuro. É comum escutarmos apresentadores de telejornais dizerem, antes de um intervalo comercial: "voltamos já", quando querem expressar que "voltarão logo" depois dos comerciais.

Outro erro comum no Brasil é conjugar incorretamente o subjuntivo. Exemplo: usar "pode" quando o correto seria "possa".

Comment: "Voltamos" também é a conjugação no presente, que deve ser a intenção do falante.