# «Vou» em «vou buscar uma maçã à cozinha» é verbo pleno ou auxiliar?

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

Consideremos as seguintes frases:

> (a) Vou buscar uma maçã.
>
> (b) Vou buscar uma maçã à cozinha.
>
> (c) Vou à cozinha buscar uma maçã.
>
> (d) Vou à cozinha.

*Vou* parece ser verbo auxiliar em (a), mas em (d) só pode ser verbo pleno. E em (b) e (c)? Por outro lado, *vou* parece ter exatamente o mesmo significado em todas as quatro frases. Mesmo em (a), há a ideia de percurso própria do verbo pleno *ir:* para ir buscar a maçã eu tenho de me deslocar, *ir*, ao lugar onde a maçã está.

Então onde é que *vou* é auxiliar e onde é que é verbo pleno? Podemos interpretá-lo como verbo pleno em (a)? Qual é o critério? Nomeadamente em (b) e (c), onde *vou* parece auxiliar *buscar*, mas onde se diz que *vou à cozinha*?

Comment: Concordo com a resposta do Jacinto que (a) pode ser considerado ambíguo, e muitas vezes vai ser sim auxiliar :) ver https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/269/2764 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em (b), (c) e (d), *ir* é pleno. (a) é um tipo de frase estruturalmente ambíguo, mas neste caso parece-me que *ir* é  também pleno.

A *Gramática do Português* tem uma caixa (páginas 1264-1266) que endereça precisamente este assunto. Passo a transcrever as partes mais relevantes:

> (i) a. A Maria *foi comprar o jornal*.
>       [...]
>
> (ii) a. A Maria foi comprar o jornal *à tabacaria*.
>        [...]
>
> [A] expressão direcional é necessariamente legitimada pelo verbo *ir* (cf. *a Maria foi à tabacaria*, [...]), e não pelo segundo verbo (cf. a impossibilidade de **a Maria comprou o jornal à tabacaria*, [...]). Por outras palavras, em (ii) a expressão direcional é um complemento do verbo *ir*, o que, dada a propriedade (A) dos verbos auxiliares [«os verbos auxiliares não selecionam argumentos»], indica que este verbo é aí pleno, não auxiliar. O conteúdo destes exemplos pode, aliás, ser expresso por frases em que fica claro, por um lado, o estatuto de *ir* como verbo pleno e, por outro, o estatuto do predicado com o verbo infinitivo como um adjunto adverbial de finalidade:
>
> (iii) a. A Maria foi à tabacaria [(para) comprar o jornal].
>         [...]
>
> Face a estes factos, é possível analisar igualmente os exemplos de (i) como envolvendo o verbo pleno *ir*, sem um complemento direcional explícito. Nestas frases, o predicado que segue o verbo *ir* é equivalente semanticamente à expressão de finalidade entre parênteses retos dos exemplos de (iii), Esse predicado, aliás, pode mesmo, em certos casos, ser reinterpretado como um complemento direcional. Assim, é perfeitamente adequado responder a uma pergunta como *aonde é que foi a Maria?* [...] unicamente com a expressão *comprar o jornal* [...].

De seguida passa-se a analisar uma outra propriedade dos verbos auxiliares: «Uma frase ativa transitiva contendo uma perífrase verbal tem o mesmo significado básico da sua contraparte passiva». Esta regra é violada tanto pelo exemplo (i) como (ii) (**o jornal foi ser comprado (à tabacaria) pela Maria*), o que sugere *ir* ser pleno em ambos os casos. De seguida, a análise volta-se para o presente:

> (iv) a. A Maria vai comprar o jornal (*à tabacaria*).
>        [...]
>   [...]
>   Sem o complemento direcional, no entanto, os exemplos (iva,b), com o verbo *ir* no presente do indicativo, contrariamente a (ia,b), com o verbo no pretérito perfeito, admitem passivização, preservando a sinonímia do par ativo-passivo. Este facto indica que, neste caso, o verbo *ir* é auxiliar: cf. *o jornal vai ser comprado pela Maria* com **o jornal foi ser comprado pela Maria*). É plausível supor, então, que nos exemplos de (iv) sem o complemento direcional e com o verbo no presente do indicativo *ir* tanto pode ser verbo auxiliar como verbo pleno. Esta ambiguidade surge sempre que o sujeito da frase é uma entidade capaz de locomoção autónoma e o seu envolvimento na situação descrita pelo predicado com o o verbo no infinitivo [...] é compatível com a sua locomoção para um lugar diferente daquele onde se encontra inicialmente.

Esta análise parece sugerir que (a) é ambígua. Mas podemos argumentar que a frase (a) não admite passivização: *uma maçã vai ser buscada* parece muito estranha e portanto (a) seria sempre um uso pleno. Não tenho a certeza de que isto não seja apenas uma idiossincrasia da evolução do verbo *buscar*, que se especializou de tal forma que a frase passiva parece estranha. Mas *buscar* significa geralmente *procurar*; só quando se associa ao verbo *ir* passa a significar *ir a algum e sítio e trazer*. *Trazer* não é o mesmo que *procurar*, mas isto parece sugerir que de facto *ir* é usado com o seu sentido de locomoção.