# A preposição «para» é facultativa em «vou ao Rio para conhecer o Pão de Açúcar»?

Tags: sintaxe, preposições

Estou em dúvida na seguinte frase:

> Vou ao Rio de Janeiro para conhecer o Pão de Açúcar.
>
> Vou ao Rio de Janeiro conhecer o Pão de Açúcar.

As duas formas estão corretas? Semanticamente, há diferença? E mais: na segunda, seria necessário o uso da vírgula antes de *conhecer*?

Comment: Do ponto de vista semântico não noto diferença entre as duas frases, nem mesmo alguma sutileza

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sim, ambas estão corretas e são semanticamente muito semelhantes. Embora a ideia de finalidade esteja mais explícita na frase com *para*, o predicado com *conhecer o Pão de Açúcar* é também no outro caso um adjunto adverbial de finalidade. Pode também, em certas frases, ser interpretado como complemento direcional:

> — Onde vais?
>   — Vou conhecer o Pão de Açúcar.

Vê também [esta pergunta,](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/vou-em-vou-buscar-uma-ma%C3%A7%C3%A3-%C3%A0-cozinha-%C3%A9-verbo-pleno-ou-auxiliar) que está relacionada.

A vírgula não é geralmente usada, já que o adjunto está depois do verbo. É mais típico usá-la se o adjunto estiver antes (caso em que *para* tem de ser incluído):

> Para conhecer o Pão de Açúcar, vou ao Rio de Janeiro.